# Gradient to background images in Carousel view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have used the library from the [link](https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow?files=1) and implemented Carousel view in android. I have decreased the spacing the between images so that the images will be back aligned . I need to apply gradient to background images except the front one and the gradient should be applied after scroll.

Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

Comment: For what I've seen, if I got your question right, you want to add a gradient to non active images. The only way is to load a xml gradient as a background of the image, and change it programmatically when the image is selected, giving it the right image

Comment: Yes I have done using XML but the gradient is not applying when we scroll the Carousel view

Comment: Might we seen some images? Some code?